# Unable to get lock when eventfd is used for synchronization

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to use eventfd for synchronization b/w two threads. Please look below code.  In this if main thread acquires a lock first it wont release unless I uncomment sleep after write function. It is true if thread gets the lock first. Please let me know how to handle without using sleep after write.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int event_fd;
uint64_t counter;
void * Thread1(void *p)
{
    printf("\n%s eventfd = %d\n",(char*)p, event_fd);

    while(1)
    {
        read(event_fd, &counter,sizeof(counter));
        printf("\n %s function counter = %llu\n",(char*)p,counter);
        sleep(1);
        write(event_fd,&counter,sizeof(counter));
        //sleep(1);     
     }

    return NULL;
}

void main()
{
    char str[]="In Thread1";
    int ret;

    pthread_t p_th;
    printf("Events demonstration pid = %d sizeof counter %lu\n ",getpid(),sizeof(counter));
    event_fd=eventfd(1,0);
    printf("event_fd %d\n",event_fd);
    pthread_create(&p_th,NULL,Thread1, str);    
    while(1)
    {
        read(event_fd, &counter,sizeof(counter));
        printf("\n In main function counter = %llu\n",counter);
        sleep(1);
        write(event_fd,&counter,sizeof(counter));   
        //sleep(1); 
    }

    pthread_exit (NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, they aren't locks. They are `eventfd` semaphores.

Secondly, they contain no provision for fairness amongst threads. So if you omit the `sleep()` clause, the semaphore will be grabbed again the moment you release it by the next `read`. `eventfd` is more often used in a producer consumer environment where one end is doing the `write` and the other the `read`.